# Custom font in Xcode 6 interface builder

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, xcode6

I heard that Xcode 6 interface builder supports custom fonts. But I don't see my custom font (which has been dragged into the project) in the font pop-up list. Am I missing anything or is that an iOS-only feature? I am building an OS X desktop app with Xcode 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed it to custom fonts before looking in the font family?

Comment: I did set the "Font" dropdown to "Custom", but I still don't see the font in the "Family" dropdown. I've added the font into the project and added the `ATSApplicationFontsPath` key in Info.plist. I am able to use that custom font in code.

Comment: Well I dragged a font into the app like you said and then when I want to select it I go into IB and select a label, then click on font and change it from system to custom. Then I scroll down the list and its there for selection. Way easier than before with all that adding it to plist and calling it by its family name etc.

Comment: Is your project a cocoa desktop project or a cocoa-touch iOS project?

Comment: Yeah tried the same process and seems to only work for iOS. There must still be some fiddling required for you, sorry couldn't help.

Comment: Wait no. Now I just imported the font into the font book(ie installed it) and now it shows up on the list.

Comment: I guess if you import the font into the font book, it will become a system-wise font. Let's me try to see if app renders correctly in an OS without the font installed.

Comment: Installing the font with the Font Book does allow me to select that font in IB and the font renders correctly in my app. However, if later I remove that font from the Font Book, the app doesn't fallback to the font in app bundle.

Comment: That sounds like what it should do? Will it still have the font available on other machines though?

Comment: The font is in app bundle, not installed in the system with Font book.